# Functions defined in application.js not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I'm working on a Rails 6 app and I'm trying to put some Javascript functionality  into my app. The code I'm using is working on non Rails template but when I put the same code into Rails 6 app application.js folder the Javascript function is not working.

```
application.js

function hideButtin(){
  var element = document.getElementById("hide");
  element.style.display = 'none';
}

header.html.erb

<%= link_to "OWNER SIGN UP", signup_path, class: "button", onclick: "hideButtin()" %>

_form.html.erb

 <div id="hide">
   <%= f.check_box :owner %>
   <%= f.label :owner %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, functions doesn't work like that in Rails 6, you need add it in `window` scope

```
function hideButtin(){
  var element = document.getElementById("hide");
  element.style.display = 'none';
}

window.hideButtin = hideButtin;
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @Rajdeep. I added  window.hideButtin = hideButtin(); stil not working.

Comment: I think you mean: `window.hideButtin = hideButtin` (no parentheses).

Comment: @rossta my bad, just edited my answer. Thanks mate.

Comment: @ZekariasZico I have edited my answer, can you please retry?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a [real event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of using `onclick`?

```
document.addEventHandler('addEventListener', 'click', function(e){
  var other_element = document.getElementById("hide");
  if (e.target.matches('.hide_on_click') && other_element) {
     other_element.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

---

```
<%= link_to "OWNER SIGN UP", signup_path, class: "button hide_on_click" %>
```

It does not mix content and behavior and you don't need to create a global. If you don't want to hardcode the id of the element you are hiding just add a data attribute with the target.